# find how many zeros there are in a complex polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

need to find how many solutions there are on re(z)>0
$$z^6-6z^5 +5z^4+5z-5=0$$
tried using Rouche, but have problems with $|z|>1$ and $|z|<1$

Comment: You can write it as $(z-1)(z^5-5z^4+5)$. Maybe that brings you further.

Comment: $|z|<0$? ?!?!?!

Comment: drhab, am I missing something?, couldn't find how to continue from your equation

Comment: Use a Möbius transform to move the right half plane to the inside of the unit circle. Or use the [Routh-Hurwitz stability criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh%E2%80%93Hurwitz_stability_criterion).

Comment: Of course, you also could just simply compute numerical approximations and check them using disk arithmetic as used in implementations of the Durand-Kerner method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crucial fact in the proof of Rouché's theorem is that

$$h_\lambda(z) = \lambda f(z) + (1-\lambda) g(z)$$

has no zeros on the boundary of the domain for any $\lambda \in [0,1]$. That ensures that

$$N(\lambda) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{h_\lambda'(z)}{h_\lambda(z)}\,dz = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial\Omega} \frac{g'(z) + \lambda(f'(z)-g'(z))}{g(z) +\lambda (f(z)-g(z))}\,dz$$

is a well-defined continuous function of $\lambda$. Since $N(\lambda)$ is the number of zeros of $h_\lambda$ in $\Omega$, it is integer-valued, and a continuous integer-valued function on $[0,1]$ is constant.

To find the number of zeros of $f(z) = z^6-6z^5+5z^4+5z-5$ in the right half-plane using Rouché's theorem, we need to choose an appropriate $\Omega$, and a $g$ satisfying the demands, whose number of zeros in the right half-plane is easily determined.

The choice of the domain isn't very interesting, it must be large enough to contain all zeros of $f$ and $g$ in the right half-plane, and unless one does a fine analysis of the behaviour of $f$, its boundary will contain an interval on the imaginary axis. A large enough half-disk is a natural choice.

So it remains to identify an appropriate $g$. If $g$ contains the $z^6$ term, on the semicircular part of $\partial\Omega$, we have

$$\lvert f(z)-g(z)\rvert \leqslant K\cdot\lvert z\rvert^5,$$

and for a large enough radius, that is smaller than $\lvert g(z)\rvert \geqslant \lvert z\rvert^6 - M\cdot \lvert z\rvert^5$, so $\lvert f-g\rvert < \lvert g\rvert$ on that part of the boundary, and that ensures that no $h_\lambda$ has a zero there.

Thus we need to look at the imaginary axis. $z^6$ is real and $\leqslant 0$ there, $-6z^5$ purely imaginary, $5z^4$ real and $\geqslant 0$, $5z$ purely imaginary, and $-5$ real and $< 0$.

Choosing $g(z) = z^6-5$, we see that $g$ takes only strictly negative real values on the imaginary axis, in particular it has no zeros there. Also, the number of zeros of $g$ in the right half-plane is easy to see (there are three).

So we need to see that $g + \lambda (f-g)$ has no zeros on the imaginary axis (at least not on the part we're concerned with). Since

$$\operatorname{Im} (f-g)(it) = -6t^5 + 5t,$$

$g + \lambda(f-g)$ can only have a zero on the imaginary axis in $0$ or in $\pm i\sqrt[4]{5/6}$, since otherwise the imaginary part is nonzero for $\lambda > 0$, and we know that $g$ has no zeros there, which takes care of $\lambda = 0$. For $t = 0$, we have $h_\lambda(0) = -5 \neq 0$ for all $\lambda$, and for $t = \pm \sqrt[4]{5/6}$, we have

$$\operatorname{Re} g(it) + \lambda(f(it) - g(it)) = -t^6 - 5 + 5\lambda t^4 = -t^6 - 5 + \lambda\frac{25}{6} \leqslant -t^6 - \frac{5}{6} < 0,$$

so $h_\lambda$ has no zeros on the imaginary axis for any $\lambda\in [0,1]$, and we see that $f$ has three zeros in the right half-plane.